# bad argument type for built-in operation when using numpy bytes_ in numba jitclass

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to use a `jitclass` that takes a fixed length `np.bytes_` as an attribute. The attribute I am trying to attach looks like this:

```
s = np.bytes_('abc')
```

I can get the corresponding numba type like this:

```
numba.from_dtype(s.dtype)
```

which returns

```
[char x 3]
```

Which is equivalent to `numba.types.CharSeq(3)`.

But if I now try to construct an object to use this, e.g.

```
@jitclass([('s', CharSeq(3))])
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

MyClass(s)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8124/1793082569.py in <module>
----> 1 MyClass(s)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\experimental\jitclass\base.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    122         bind = cls._ctor_sig.bind(None, *args, **kwargs)
    123         bind.apply_defaults()
--> 124         return cls._ctor(*bind.args[1:], **bind.kwargs)
    125 
    126 

TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

Note that I get a different error if the types don't match, e.g. if the string was longer than 3.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

(This is running numba 0.54.1 from conda-forge on Windows with Python 3.9.7 and numpy 1.20.3)

Comment: The problem is even simpler to create with a function and shows that there is some inconsistency in the treatment of numpy base types vs vectors of the same types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71859576/why-does-numba-work-on-numpy-string-vectors-but-not-on-numpy-strings

Comment: AFAIK `CharSeq` is not meant to be used as a standalone type, only as an item type in Numpy arrays for example.

Comment: @JérômeRichard is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so. Note this type is experimental and it is put in the module `npytypes`.