# Why does numba work on numpy string vectors but not on numpy strings?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Consider the simplest possible function

```
@numba.jit
def foo(s1):
    return s1
```

Now constructing an array of `np.bytes_` objects

```
> a = np.array(['abc']*5, dtype='S5')
> a
array([b'abc', b'abc', b'abc', b'abc', b'abc'], dtype='|S5')
```

Why does calling `foo` with the vector work:

```
> foo(a)
array([b'abc', b'abc', b'abc', b'abc', b'abc'], dtype='|S5')
```

But calling `foo` with a single element raises an exception

```
> foo(a[0])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8124/2559272744.py in <module>
----> 1 foo(a[0])

TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

(This is running numba 0.54.1 from conda-forge on Windows with Python 3.9.7 and numpy 1.20.3)

Comment: Your `a` is an array.  The function doesn't have to do anything with the dtype.  `a[0]` is a `numpy.bytes_` object, not an array or subclass of array.  `a[[0]]` is still an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `bytes` nor `np.bytes_` types are listed in [the set of types supported by `numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/numpysupported.html#scalar-types) as of the latest release. The closest things it supports would be:

1. Character sequences (read: `str`) (though it specifically says "no operations are available on them", so this is pretty useless); your function would work if you called `foo(a[0].decode())` to make it text (but only because it's a pretty useless function)
2. Actual `numpy` arrays; the cost to view the `bytes`/`np.bytes_` as an `np.array` is pretty low, so you could just do: `foo(np.frombuffer(a[0], np.uint8))` and produce something that is more programmatically useful and represents the same data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't understand your point 1) - Character sequences are supposed to be supported, and `numba.from_dtype(a[0].dtype)` returns `[char x 3]` which is the same as `numba.types.CharSeq(3)`. (Though this little test has pointed me to the fact that the type of the array and the type of element in it are inconsistent, which would explain why numba might struggle)

Answer (score 1):

The `bytes` type is **barely supported** like the `str` type. They are very *inefficiently* supported and the support is minimalist. Moreover, there are some opened related bugs (like [this one](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/7921). Furthermore, AFAIK, there is no plan to work on this any time soon.

From my understanding, `a[0]` returns a `numpy.bytes_`-typed object which is not completely compatible with `bytes` (at least for Numba). Compiling the function with `numpy.bytes_` appear to cause a bug that makes Numba being confused between `numpy.bytes_` and `bytes` (Numba try to use a compiled function with the wrong type).

Indeed, the following code works:

```py
@numba.jit
def foo(s1):
    return s1

foo(b'test')      # Works
foo(bytes(a[0]))  # Works
```

The following code fails:

```py
@numba.jit
def foo(s1):
    return s1

foo(a[0])         # Fail and cause a bug
foo(bytes(a[0]))  # Now fail (do not recompile the function properly)
foo(b'test')      # Also fail (do not recompile the function properly)
```

Note that the `bytes` type is only supported in read-only mode.